# When does $C_b(X)$ admit a Schauder Basis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a separable and connected metric space.  My question is rather short and to the point: do there exist $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ such that
$$
\left\{d(x_n,\cdot)-d(x_0,\cdot)\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty},
$$
is a Schauder basis of $C_b(X)$?  If so, what is this "basis" called in the literature?

Comment: Do you know any example where $C_b(X)$ is separable, yet does not admit a Schauder basis?

Comment: Note: Consider $X = \mathbb N$ with the discrete metric.  Then $C_b(X) = l^\infty$ is not separable.  Thus no Schuder basis.  Is there any non-compact $X$ where $C_b(X)$ is separable?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Actually not (now that you mention in), so I refined my question (so that is directly to the point of the manner)

I also just noticed the discrete counter-example (as usual these are pathological) so I added the connectedness condition.

Comment: Isn't it straightforward to embed $C_B(\mathbb{N})$ in $C_B(\mathbb{R})$ via zigzag-curves?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker What do you mean?

Comment: Two remarks which might be of interest. 1. A standard reference on your topic is the Springer Lecture Notes "Schauder Bases in Banach Spaces of Continuous Functions" by Z. Semadeni.  2. As a general rule of thumb, if you want to extend results and concepts on spaces of bounded, continuous functions on compact spaces to the  non-compact case (Gelfand-Naimark, duality for bounded Radon measures, tensor product representations,...), one way to go is to replace the norm by  the strict topology (R.C. Buck), i.e., the finest l.c. topology which agrees with compact convergence on the unit ball.

Comment: @Carl_Petterson Take any element $f$ of $C_B(\mathbb{N})$. For each $n$, let  $f(n\pm 1/2)=0$ and connect the values of  $f(n\pm 1/2)$ and $f(n)$ by a straight line.

Comment: The original Banach space basis was constructed naturally and  explicitly in $C([0.1])$ by Schauder (hence the name). It is in Banach's book. This shows, by Milyutin's theorem, that there is a positive answer for any non countable compact metric soace.

Comment: @bathalf15320 Ah I wasn't aware of Milyutin's result (though I do know of the strict topology; as an example of colimits in the category of LCSs); is Milyutin's isometry explicit or is there currently only an existence version of the theorem known?

Comment: I only know of an existence proof using the Pełczyński decomposition method so it won't give an explicit basis.  For these, I would try Semadeni.

Comment: @Carl_Petterson, this is far from isometry, only isomorphism. Otherwise it would have contradicted the Banach-Stone theorem.

Comment: @TomaszKania Very nice point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in order for $C_b(X)$ to have a Schauder basis, $X$ has to be compact. Indeed, $C_b(X)$ is naturally isomorphic to $C(\beta X)$ and the latter is non-separable (because $\beta X$ is non-metrisable) [as long as $X$ is a non-compact metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217422/17929).

Thus, you are in the realm of compact metric space to have a chance for a Schauder basis of some specific form since $C(X)$ always has a Schauder basis for a compact metric connected space. But do you have a basis of the required form already for $C[0,1]$?

Comment: @TomaszKanie I was hopeing to use this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1529